# Rails + nginx - work together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I installed passenger, nginx (1.2.1) and Rails 3.2.3. However I keep using WebBrick as a server for Rails because I can't figure out how to make them work together. In other words, how to run a website, I'm working on, on nginx.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you looking for a development environment solution or a production one?

Comment: nginx + passenger is a great server side production environment solution. For development, you dont need the overhead of 2 servers (nginx+passenger). You could include "unicorn"/"puma"/"thin" in your Gemfile in the development group and then run "rails s thin" to get a better server than webrick in your development environment.

Comment: yes, Nginx+Unicorn https://gist.github.com/3052776

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions on the web includin nginx and thin which is a good combination. Here is one that worked for me:

http://blog.expertura.de/posts/17

Also one very good but in german (of cause code is still correct):

http://www.netzlogger.de/2010/02/rails-applikationen-mit-nginx-und-thin.html